# PHP Not Inserting Records Into MySQL Table From CSV Which Content Special Character

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i am inserting record into mysql table from CSV but php code skip all those enteries which content " ' " in CSV file. its working fine with normal data
working fine with , Jams Bond , but skipping this data : jam's bond

```
function readCSV($csvFile)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
    {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        fclose($file_handle);
    }

    $csvFile = $target_file;
    $csv = readCSV($target_file);
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($csv);$i++)
    {                                       
        if($i>=0)
        {
            if($csv[$i][3]!='')
            {
                $dd=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($csv[$i][2]));
                mysqli_query($conn123,"insert into call_detail_record (date, caller_id_from,extension, caller_id_to, duration, cost, destination, cost_rate, cost_centre) values('".$dd."','".$csv[$i][3]."','".$csv[$i][4]."','".$csv[$i][5]."','".$csv[$i][6]."','".$csv[$i][7]."','".$csv[$i][8]."','".$csv[$i][10]."','".$csv[$i][11]."')");    
            }
        }
        if($i==(sizeof($csv)-1))
        {
        ?>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label><font color="#009933">File Uploaded Successfully...</font></label>
            </div>
            <?php
            unlink($target_file);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: use mysqli_real_escape_string () on each variable or use prepared statements. Obs... the way you are using msqli you you are still vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @JulioSoares where yo use this ? can you send me the code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to escape the quotes

```
$dd=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($csv[$i][2]));

/* escaping */
$csv[$i][3] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][3]);
$csv[$i][4] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][4]);
$csv[$i][5] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][5]);
$csv[$i][6] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][6]);
$csv[$i][7] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][7]);
$csv[$i][8] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][8]);
$csv[$i][10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][10]);
$csv[$i][11] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, $csv[$i][11]);

mysqli_query($conn123,"insert into call_detail_record 
(date, caller_id_from, extension, caller_id_to, 
 duration, cost, destination, cost_rate, cost_centre)
values ('".$dd."','".$csv[$i][3]."','".$csv[$i][4]."','".$csv[$i][5]. "','".
$csv[$i][6]."','".$csv[$i][7]."','".$csv[$i][8]."','".
$csv[$i][10]."','".$csv[$i][11]."')");
```

Same for querying...

```
$mysearch = = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn123, "andrew's");

mysqli_query($conn123,"SELECT * from call_detail_record WHERE 
                       caller_id_from ='" . $mysearch . "'");
```

Comment: it'll add jame's into database ? i mean it'll not skip this entry ?

Comment: yes it resolved but now i am getting another issue
when searching with where query 
andrew's   this give me an error because where firstname='andrew's' becomes invalid query

Comment: Every time you want to pass a variable from PHP to mysqli using the sintax you are using you must 'clean' the variable with `mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $your_variable);`

Comment: I have edited the answer to show an example. Again **Alert!** Your are vulnerable to SQL Injection using this syntax!!! You must use prepared statements if you care about your data.